# How to format a string as Vietnamese currency?

Tags: c#, string-formatting, currency-formatting

If I set Format in [Region and Language] to US...

```
CultureInfo cul = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
string decimalSep = cul.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;//decimalSep ='.'
string groupSep = cul.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator;//groupSep=','
sFormat = string.Format("#{0}###", groupSep);
string a = double.Parse(12345).ToString(sFormat);
```

The result is: `12,345` (is correct)

But if I set the format in [Region and Language] to VietNam, then the result is: `12345`

The result should be `12.345`.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Then how to they write this of `en-us` `12,345.23` ? Is it 12.345.23?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal 12.345,23 See [Decimal mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are helping too much.  The format specifier is culture insensitive, you always use a comma to indicate where the grouping character goes.  Which is then substituted by the actual grouping character when the string is formatted.

This formats correctly:

```
        CultureInfo cul = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("vi-VN");   // try with "en-US"
        string a = double.Parse("12345").ToString("#,###", cul.NumberFormat);
```

You should actually use "#,#" to ensure it still works in cultures that have a uncommon grouping.  It wasn't clear from the question whether that mattered or not so I punted for "#,###"

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
var value = 8012.34m;
var info = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("vi-VN");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(info, "{0:c}", value));
```

The result is:

```
8.012,34 ₫
```

Oh, and with the value `12345` the result is `12.345,00 ₫`.