# How to covert a string from report table in c# to Vietnamese currency?

Tags: c#, report, currency

I have a c# report that contains one String column represent the currency.

Now I try to convert the String value to currency:

```
= FormatCurrency(Fields!SOTIEN_GUI.Value, 0)
```

That works, but the value is now US currency (EX: $ 7.000)

What have I do to to get the result like "₫ 7.000" ?

Thanks.

Comment: it's c# report expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you have created .rdlc report file. To set Current region settings, so to display currency in the format you'd prefer, you should to do next.

First, you should find Language report property. To do that, just click free place around you report objects. In the Properties window, VS will display the properties for the report.

Second, find there Language property, and change it to those, that you like. Btw, it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678506/currency-symbol-is-changed-when-i-moved-to-second-page-in-rdlc-report).

So, you'll get something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using FormatCurrency you could use the ToString() Method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx
you maybe take a look at this thread: [How to format a string as Vietnamese currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225182/how-to-format-a-string-as-vietnamese-currency)
as you can see it's possible to use the ToString() Method (or like in the example the string.Format() Method):

```
var value = 8012.34m;
var info = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("vi-VN");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(info, "{0:c}", value));
```

Comment: sorry, but in my context it has to be the report expression.
thank you.

Comment: yea! Thank @bema so much!

Because in my context it has to be a report expression, so I "transfer" your code to:
=String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("vi-VN"), "{0:c}", value)
It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in some special context, like Excel or something? In regular C#, I think what you want to do is use something like:

```
moneyValue.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("vi-VN"));
```

Comment: Yes. It's a report expression in c#. I try to use your command but it's not the valid expression. Thank you.